# How to visualise STL container contents in debugger using Clion and GCC on an M1 Mac

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clion, lldb

I have a large C++ project that makes use of C++20 features and I'd like to be able to work on it using CLion on an M1 Mac. Since clang doesn't yet support all of C++20, I have installed g++-12 and configured Clion to use this.

Everything seems to work fine, except when debugging I cannot see a reasonable visualisation of the contents of STL containers.

For a simple Hello World with a vector:

[image]

If I switch the C++ compiler back to default (clang) in toolchains, it produces a nice visualisation as expected.

[image]
I've tried unchecking/checking the "Enable GNU C++ library renderers" option in Debugger->Data Views->C++, and supplying "stdlib=libstdc++" as mentioned here https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/02/clion-eap-news-cmake-3-1-stl-renderers-in-debugger-pty-and-more/.

Neither have made a difference.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: These visualizations are provide by lldb's "data formatters": https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html.  lldb does have some support for the GCC standard C++ libraries's types, though it isn't as complete as the Clang support  You can tell whether the problem is "no formatter" or "not working formatter" by running the `type synthetic info <some_vector_variable>`.  If there is a formatter for these types, it will name it.  If there isn't, the someone will have to write one.  Either have a go yourself, or file a request to the llvm.org bug tracker: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same question as yours. And I have solved it..Here is my situation:

At first, I used MinGW-w64 GDB `8.1` as my debugger. I couldn't see `vector` directly either.

I upgraded the GDB version to `13.1`, and then it was ok.